# Java println inserting extra new line

Tags: java, eclipse, newline, println

This is bugging the heck out of me. For whatever reason, System.out.println is inserting an extra newline and I don't understand why. The code in question is:

```
System.out.println("Videos: ");
for (Video video: videosToBeRented) {
    System.out.println(video.getName() + " - " + video.getType());
}
System.out.println("price: " + price + "\n");
```

And here is a sample output:

```
Videos: 
The Walking Dead Cats - ROMANCE

Star Scrimmage - HORROR

Cat in the Boot - NEW_RELEASE
price: 91.0
```

A Video is a simple class that contains two private instance variables String name and VideoType type. VideoType is an enumeration.

Any ideas why the first two is skipping a space where the last one doesn't? I am using Eclipse. Maybe there is a setting that I have accidentally hit.

Thanks!

***UPDATE
Adding Video and VideoType classes.

```
public class Video {

//Private Instance Variables
private String name;
private VideoType type;

public Video(String name, VideoType type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public VideoType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(VideoType type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

```
public enum VideoType {
NEW_RELEASE(6.00), DRAMA(5.00), COMEDY(2.00), ROMANCE(4.00), HORROR(3.00);

private double price;

VideoType(double price) {

    this.price = price;
}

public double getPrice() {

    return this.price;
}
```

}

Comment: `println()` by default creates a new line. If you want to print a line and add your own newline character `\n` just use `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aye, it was an incredibly silly mistake.

You guys helped me to get to the solution. What happened was I was reading in in the video names from a txt file that looked like this:

```
movie1,
movie2,
...
```

I set the delimiter as "," so it was reading "movie1" and then "\r\nmovie2"

I need to either change the text file so that it looks like: movie1,movie2, or change my code to read in by line instead of just reading in the next value.

Comment: You can read line by line so I would go that route if that seems better to you.

Answer (score 8):

Possible cause is `video.getType().toString()` value ends with new line character(`'\n'`). Try `System.out.print`, see if you still get new line character. Another alternative is to use debugger to examine characters.

Comment: I set String aString = video.getName() + " - " + video.getType(); In debugger, I examined aString as: [, T, h, e,  , W, a, l, k, i, n, g,  , D, e, a, d,  , C, a, t, s,  , -,  , H, O, R, R, O, R]

Comment: @btbam91 When Java see your `video.getType()` it will make the value to a String using `toString()` of whatever the value `getType()` returns. @Adi said you might wanna check the actual value of the `getType()` returns. That may contains a new line character.

Answer (score 2):

```
\n
```

this insets a new line.  then everything would have its own line without skipping an extra line.  The issue here seems to be from you `getType();` call.

you also could keep the \n and do `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` as print ln prints a new line.

edit: now that you posted your code we can see that it's the "VideoType" class.  Have you tried returning the enum values without the parameter?

I would create a toString method and display what you want yourself which will get rid of that extra line issue.

This way when you end with `video.getType();` you will be sure it acts the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.out.print` to avoid extra line.

Comment: I understand the difference between print and println. I'm trying to understand why println is not behaving the way I expect it to.

Comment: can you please update video class code. might be toString is override and its adding newline

Answer (score -1):

Try `System.out.print("someString")` instead of `System.out.println("someString")`